# Установка амплитуды выходного сигнала. Дистанционное управление генератора сигнала 33250A

Tags: c++, qt, генераторы

Мне с помощью дистационного управления нужно задать частоту выходного сигнала, амплитуду выходного сигнала и установить напряжение смещения. Никаких проблем с 1 и 3 пунктом нет. Без проблем в документации нашёл как задать частоту и напряжение. С помощью команд Freq <значение> и Voltage:OffSet <значение>. А вот с амплитудой проблемы, в документации указан только способ через переднюю панель.
И моя проблема, что я никак не могу найти с помощью какой команды можно это сделать.
Я искал в целом по краткому справочнику SCPI, там была следующая команда Pow:Ampl <значение>. Однако на моем Agilent 33250A данная команда не работает, а моя программа созданная в Qt Creator просто зависает.
Конечно проблемы могут быть и в моём коде, однако. Все остальные команды из документации по генератору 33250A выполняются без каких-либо проблем

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[page 131](https://www.keysight.com/my/en/assets/9018-03925/user-manuals/9018-03925.pdf):

```
APPLy
:SINusoid [\<frequency\> [,\<amplitude\> [,\<offset\>] ]]
```

- это не оно?

Или

```
VOLTage {<amplitude>|MINimum|MAXimum}
```

Comment: Да, второй вариант именно то, что нужно. Большое спасибо. Как-то пропустил мимо глаз данную команду. Зациклился на AMPL и не увидел..

Comment: Нужно использовать первоисточники. Предположу, что судя по этому "Freq <значение>", вы пользовались переведённой на русский язык инструкцией. В оригинальной инструкции я быстро нашёл то, что нужно по слову "amplitude".